# Error on Inserting data into database

Tags: c#, database, insert

I have 3 Textboxes called, `TxtFirstName`, `TxtMiddleName` and `TxtLastName`. I would like to insert this info to the database where my column name is just FullName. I would want my 3 Information to join to insert them into one. What I did is :

```
string _fullname = _lastname + "," + _firstname + middlename;
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableVote (FullName) VALUES ('" + _fullname + "')", sc);
```

but it seems that it gets me an error. 
"String or Binary data would be truncated. The Statement has been terminated."

How do i correct this ?

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: make sure your full name column is long enough to support the string length.

Comment: sorry, i'm still new in programming. How do i prevent from sql injection?

Comment: Nit: I would *not* store the full name. Instead, I would either use a *computed column* or I would apply *rules on usage* (when fetched). Also, annoyingly (to deal with), some people have no first name, two middle names, a prefix/suffice, etc ..

Comment: it has to do with length.  Open your sql database and make sure that your column has enough length to support that.

Comment: @sircapsalot I disagree with that "advice". **Using placeholders *is* learning the basics.** Considering that it's a no-effort approach with ADO.NET (and it actually *cleans up the code*), it should *always* be done. This is what I *mandate* of acceptable code from junior developers - any deviation should be quickly addressed to teach good *basic* habits.

Comment: @sircapsalot Doesn't matter. Bad habits are bad habits. They *must* be addressed ASAP. If you let a puppy ..

Comment: What is the length of your FullName column in the TableVote table? What is happening here is that the fullname column is not wide enough for the data you are inserting.

Comment: @sircapsalot  I think this is one of those areas where parameterization is an accepted best practice and concatenation is an accepted worst practice.  We should never even teach query building by concatenation.

Comment: Thanks all. I did what you said. and i'll practice parametrized commands from now on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that your string is longer than the maximum length allowed for the column. You either need to adjust your schema to allow longer values or truncate the value you insert.

Also: You should really use parametrized commands:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableVote (FullName) VALUES (@fullname)");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", _fullname);
```

Read up on Sql Injection attacks.

**Update**: As mentioned by others you should contemplate storing the name in different columns (i.e. `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`. Otherwise you throw away information which will be hard to recompute (e.g. try making a statistic of the most common middle name with your schema).

Comment: Thanks for this ChrisWue, I really appreciate it. And yes, I will practice parameterized commands :)

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, the value you are inserting into your table is too long for the column specification.

HOWEVER

I've been working with databases for quite a while now, and I'd like to advise you to please not store the name all in one column. I've seen this over and over again. It seems like a good, quick idea at the time, but sooner or later, you'll have a requirement where you need to get just part of the name. Once you reach that point, you'll find yourself with all kinds of problems, because names are very, very complicated things that are highly dependent on language and culture. Given a list of whole names, think about how you would parse out just the last names. At first, it seems very simple, until you consider all the special cases, like people with two last names ("Harper-Smith"), last names from other cultures ("St. James", "O'Connell", "Van der Wall"), etc.

Just consider saving the name in three parts in three columns, it doesn't take much and it will save you a lot of trouble later.